# add API currency convert to postres table in python

Tags: python, postgresql, api

I have an exercise to do:

Through library psycopg2 connect with my database and get top 10 customers along with their credit limit:

```
import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect(
    host='host',
    user='user',
    password='password',
    dbname='db_name',
)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT customername, creditlimit FROM customers order by 2 desc limit 10')


for row in cursor:
    row[0]
    row[1]
    print(f"{row[0]}: {row[1]} USD")
```

This is the result of the query above:

[image]

As per next step I need to connect with API and convert this creditlimit to different currencies (EUR, JPY, GBP), so the final output will be like that:

```
Euro+ Shopping Channel: 227600.00 USD / 187183.93EUR / 24017262.40 JPY /160578.63 GBP
...
```

This is the code for API (the key is valid, feel free to test):

```
headers = {
    "apikey": "b6iGXz0JZcr2iyV0SeLcd0dEpqOr8ngK"
}

currency = ['EUR', 'JPY', 'GBP']

params = {
    "from": "USD",
    "to": 'EUR',
    "amount": row[1]
}

url = "https://api.apilayer.com/exchangerates_data/convert"

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
```

I connected with API, but I have difficulties to append it to my sql data, please advise.

Comment: What difficulty are you facing?

Comment: I am trying to convert the given credit limits to different currencies (using API) and then attach it to my sql query results.